# Modify content of event object [JQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace a string on event object but I can't change the `onclick` attribute.

Any solution?

Thanks!

```
//elemento imagen referente al boton del calendario
var imgElement = $(element).parent("div").find("img");

var newImgOnClick = (imgElement.attr("onclick") + "").replace(idNeto + "1",idNeto + numeroLotes);

imgElement.attr("onclick",newImgOnClick);
```

Comment: this seems like a xy problem why do you need to edit the onclick attribute?

Comment: I am cloning dynamic forms with calendar widgets fields. And I have to change the onclick attr of img widgets in the new forms for it run ok. I have problems when change onclick attr with string

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgElement = $(element).parent("div").find("img");

var newImgOnClick = imgElement.attr("onclick" ,idNeto + "1",idNeto + numeroLotes);

imgElement.attr("onclick",newImgOnClick);
```

Comment: replacing the value of attribute on click is same as replacing the attribute value .is this you are expected?

Comment: I only want replace a string of value, I dont want replace all value. This is the problem. Thanks!